# android:whay setOnItemClickListener not work in getLayoutInflater().inflate

Tags: android

I am creating an app which requires same Navigation Drawer for all activities. To do so, I have created a class which extends Activity (need for child classes) and written the code for Navigation Drawer there. but not work in setOnItemClickListener

this work for me

```
public class MyDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
protected RelativeLayout fullLayout;
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
@Override
public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
    fullLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mydrawer, null);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);
    super.setContentView(fullLayout);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout3);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), menuItem.getTitle().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_5_reasons).setChecked(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:id="@+id/drawer_framelayout">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
android:background="#fefefd" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

for use:

```
public class yourclass extends MyDrawer {
```

but no find item in

```
 listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                      int position, long id) {
 // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
 Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what listView has to do with your navigation drawer. 
If you're trying to set onItemClickListener on the items of your navigation drawer, it should be set in setNavigationItemSelectedListener and do whatever you want OnNavigationItemSelected().

```
private void setUpDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView){
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            doWhateverYouWant(menuItem);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Since the navigation drawer is the same for all the activities extending the MyDrawer class, I assume the function is the same for all the activities. If not, you can call the same method (setUpDrawerContent(NavigationView nv)), at the child activity.

Comment: what do you mean by that? Looking at layout xml, the navigationview is just a NavigationView. Perhaps show where you got the listView from?